# Background color opacity different on phone than on interface builder

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, interface-builder, opacity

I am setting the background color of the parent `View` to a color and set its opacity to `24%` using the `Hex color #` and the `opacity` inputs in the `Interface Builder`.

In the Interface Builder, everything looks fine:

[image: Interface Builder Background Color]

But on the device:

[image: Device View Background Color]

Here's where I set it up:

[image]

How can I solve this? I want it to look like in the IB (not dark).

Comment: Could u mark to which color you refer ? Table view background ?

Comment: Both parent `View`'s and `Table View`'s color are the same. But, for simplicity, the parent `View`'s. It's very dark.

Comment: It seems like modifing parent background opacity is affecting whole of the screen. Btw. why don't you use the same color without opacity ? Recalculate the background color with 24% opacity, create new one and apply it to the view. It would be more efficient

Comment: It's voluntarily done. The Table View has clear color and also its cells. The problem is that the color appears very dark compared to the IB one.

Comment: Are you setting the background color of the view from somewhere else, programatically  or adding the view as subview to some dark colored view?

Comment: No. It happens in all screens and they all have different code. Nothing programatically.

Comment: Did u run an app on device?

Comment: @yerpy Please be attentive and don't try to guess the solution. The second screenshot is from the device.

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru Hmm, I wouldn't ask such question when u've posted more informations, not only screen and that you have background color with opacity, there is no way we can analize what is realy happening.

Comment: You can, it's something about the settings. I just opened up another empty project and just set the background view to this color. Still darkish. It might be an Apple bug.